# Error with JuMP and Ipopt

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am trying to use JumP and Ipopt under Julia v0.7.0. When I try to construct a model:

```
julia> m = Model(solver=IpoptSolver())
```

I get the following error message:

```
Feasibility problem with:
 * 0 linear constraints
 * 0 variables
Solver is Error showing value of type Model:
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{SubString{String},1} at index [2]
```

I am using the following versions of the packages:

```
Ipopt v0.4.0
JuMP v0.18.2
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JuMP v0.18.2 does not support Julia v0.7, see [this post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jump-and-julia-0-7-1-0/12964/5).

If you want to use JuMP with Julia v0.7 or Julia v1.0 you should just the in-development version of JuMP that will be released as JuMP v0.19 when it is ready.

**EDIT**: JuMP v0.18.3 now supports Julia v1.0.

Comment: It should work now with v0.18.3 right? But it doesn't